# How to set different label for different Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I have an app and I want to set different label for different activities in my app. Think I can change the mainfest file.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".NumbersActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".FamilyActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ColorsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".PhrasesActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `label` here.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".NumbersActivity"
              android:label="Number Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".FamilyActivity"
              android:label="Family Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".ColorsActivity" 
              android:label="Color Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".PhrasesActivity"
              android:label="Phrases Activity" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:label="string resource"` inside `<activity>` tag

```
    <activity android:name=".NumbersActivity"
              android:label="string resource" />
    <activity android:name=".FamilyActivity" 
              android:label="string resource" />
    <activity android:name=".ColorsActivity"
              android:label="string resource" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> android:label="@string/name"

Add this line in  every activity manifest

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this, Use label keyword like `android:label="My New Activity"`

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".NumbersActivity"
    android:label="@string/category_numbers"
    android:theme="@style/category_numbers" />
```